# Elixir Simple module produces "Argument Error" only

Tags: elixir

I have a simple, stand alone module that yields:

```
elixir impl_bad.ex
** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

In iex:

```
=> iex
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.9.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> c "impl_bad.ex"

== Compilation error in file impl_bad.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) argument error

** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

The code:

```
defmodule ImplBad do
  def run_addition_problems(aconfig) do
    do_addition_problems(aconfig)
  end
end
```

Place this 5 line code in a file by itself.

I know do_addition_problems() does not
exist but I would expect an undefined error
with a line number.

I extracted this code from a project file where
do_addition_problems() does exists.

I would expect a bit more information from the
compiler. I had to perform a "binary search" from
a module about 1k LOC to pinpoint this problem.

Is this a problem with elixir 1.9.4?

Comment: Looks like it's indeed the problem with the Elixir version. When I try locally on Elixir `1.9.2`, it gives me `ArgumentError` just like yours. When I try `1.9.4-opt-21`, it gives a nice `(CompileError) t.ex:3: undefined function do_addition_problems/1`. I use `asdf` tool to switch between the versions of elixir. So it must be something that was fixed in the compiler between 1.9.2 and 1.9.4.

Comment: Although if I do `docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD"/t.ex:/tmp/t.ex elixir:1.9.2-slim elixir /tmp/t.ex`, I am getting a good error message, same as `elixir:1.9.4-slim`. Maybe it's about OTP version rather than Elixir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue of using `Erlang/OTP 23` *and* `Elixir 1.9.4` simultaneously.

*Elixir 1.9* is *older* than *OTP 23*, but [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) fully leverages OTP, so it relies on some warnings/messages coming from [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) compiler during compilation.

That said, downgrading *OTP* to the version `Elixir 1.9` is aware of (*21* would be fine, I believe,) *or* upgrading *Elixir* to the recent `1.11.1` would fix the issue producing fancy

```
== Compilation error in file /tmp/test.ex ==
** (CompileError) /tmp/test.ex:3: undefined function do_addition_problems/1
    (elixir 1.11.1) src/elixir_locals.erl:114: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
    (stdlib 3.13.2) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Comment: Yes, Aleksei. As a noobie I learn by making mistakes and accepting solutions from the much more experienced.

Elixir 1.11.1 and Erlang/OTP 23 together work fine.

Thank you. :) :)